# How to debug a failing Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, syntax-error

I keep getting errors on the user: (play) in the playbook. Ansible seeems to be complaining about the colon, but nothing I try works.

---

```
- hosts: all
  become: root
  tasks:

  -name: add user Natasha

    user:
    - name: natasha
    - comment:"Natasha Ping"
    - uid: 1027
    - group: ping

  -name: add user John

    user:
    - name: john
    - comment:"John Pong"
    - uid: 1028
    - group: ping
```

The expected result is that user natasha and john will be created on the hosts intended.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please edit them into your question, in a formatted block.

Comment: Your YAML is **entirely** not YAML, or at least not the structure you were expecting. Try feeding that text into any one of the yaml2json tools and you'll see that you must separate the key from the "list indicator", like `- name: add user Natasha` not what you have of `-name:`

Answer (score 2):

Your YAML syntax has errors, pretty simple to fix. YAML is strict about spacing and the separators as Matthew noted.

This is your corrected syntax:

```
---

- hosts: all
  become: root
  tasks:

  - name: add user Natasha
    user:
      name: natasha
      comment: "Natasha Ping"
      uid: 1027
      group: ping

  - name: add user John
    user:
      name: john
      comment: "John Pong"
      uid: 1028
      group: ping
```

I'd also recommend using [ansible-lint](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint). It will help you spot errors and follow best practices.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. It worked. Can you please point me to a document that give a good explanation on how spacing and dash work?

Comment: @Smith the link Matt posted is the canonical reference and has info about Ansible specific syntax. I also reference the "[Lean YAML in Y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/)" article regularly.